# How to create a fresh profile in about:profiles?

Tags: firefox, user-profiles

Firefox has a profile manager in `about:profiles`. I created a new profile to troubleshoot compatibility issues, but absolutely everything including addons and `about:config` entries was moved to the new profile.

I can't understand as this is the description on the page:

> This page helps you to manage your profiles. Each profile is a separate world which contains separate history, bookmarks, settings and add-ons.

How to reset everything to the default in the new profile?

Comment: Just tried it out myself. Created a new profile through `about:profiles` and none of the addons, bookmarks, etc, followed over to the new profile.

Comment: Rename both Firefox user folder in `%LocalAppData%` and `%AppData%` folder. Open Firefox and it will create a new profile.

Comment: @n8te: Did you press "next" and "finish" in the profile wizard, no custom changes? It may be necessary the refresh Firefox to solve this issue of mine.

Comment: @Biswa: Does this yield different results than [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1240435/598527)?

Comment: Yep, just "next" and "finish." No custom changes at all.

Comment: idk about this `about:profiles` page but you can just rename your entire "profiles" folder to something else, start Firefox and it will create a completely fresh profile for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to create a new profile using Firefox's alternative [profile manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

> **Important**: Before you can start the Profile Manager, Firefox must be completely closed.

---

> 1. Press  <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on the keyboard. A Run dialog will open.
> 2. In the Run dialog box, type in: `firefox.exe -P`
>      Note: You can use `-P`, `-p` or `-ProfileManager`.
> 3. Click `OK`. The Firefox Profile Manager (Choose User Profile) window should open.

Comment: The Mozilla support page has no instructions for other operating systems.

Comment: Running that (without `.exe`, of course) on terminal on archlinux worked fine.

Comment: Adding the parameter `--no-remote` allows you to use the profile manager while Firefox is running, but of course you will not be able to modify or load any profiles currently active.

Answer (score 6):

It might be easier to do it manually.

Go here: `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`

Then create a new folder.

Then edit `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini`

And add a new section like:

```
[Profile1]
Name=my-test-profile
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/the-name-of-the-folder
```

You can also change this to `0` in the file to get it to prompt for the profile you want:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1
```

Comment: While the process for creating a new profile is correct, this method either isn't unfortunately working for me. I will likely refresh Firefox.